# How to enable screen reader to start reading from a particular element of DOM?

Tags: html, dom, screen-readers

I want the screen reader to start reading from on image tag on the web page. There are some top level menus on the page which I don't want to be read in the beginning but towards the end.

Is it possible to do so (with ARIA or any other way), without setting focus on that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question so I might not be answering the right thing.  Are you wanting to force the screen reader to start reading the page starting at a specific object?  Focus is the right way to do that.

The screen reader user can customize their screen reader to read the entire page when it initially loads or to just read the current object.  It's totally up to the user.  You can't force the entire page to be read, nor would you want to (because you'd be overriding their custom settings).

If you don't set the focus on the object you want read first, then you are treating sighted and visually impaired users differently.  For the visually impaired user, you think an object is important enough to want the screen reader to read it first.  But for the sighted user, you don't think that object is important enough to put the initial focus there.  Why is there a difference?